# ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: javascript, react-native, stack, react-navigation

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':tasks'.

> Could not create task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin'.
> No enum constant org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.PropertiesProvider.JvmTargetValidationMode.WARN�NG

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 1m 11s
error Failed to install the app.

I want to install the navigation and start the emulator

If I did the processes in rect navigation. Later:

1)npm i
2)cd .\android
3)./gradlew clean
4)cd ..
5)npm run start
6)npm run android
7)npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli
8)npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
9)npm i jetifier
10)npx jetify
11)npx add react-native-gesture-handler@2.8.0
12)npm i
13)cd .\android
14)./gradlew clean
15)cd ..
16)npm run start
17)npm run android